# latexmk does not understand white space in \bibliography (and gives no warning)

Tags: bibtex, latexmk

I have switched to MiKTeX's `latexmk`. However, this is what I get with a regular document:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Jan. 2018, version: 4.55.
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex Bug'...
Rule 'bibtex Bug': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'Bug.bbl'
Latexmk: I WON'T RUN 'bibtex Bug' because I don't find the following files:
   IEEEabrv.bib
Latexmk: All targets (Bug.dvi) are up-to-date
```

I have minimized my example to this `Bug.tex`, with an empty `MyBib.bib` alongside it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \cite{foo}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{MyBib, IEEEabrv}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, if I invert the order of `MyBib, IEEEabrv`, it's `MyBib.bib` that is not found:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Jan. 2018, version: 4.55.
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex Bug'...
Rule 'bibtex Bug': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'Bug.bbl'
Latexmk: I WON'T RUN 'bibtex Bug' because I don't find the following files:
   MyBib.bib
Latexmk: All targets (Bug.dvi) are up-to-date
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? Can `latexmk` not find two `.bib` in different folders?

Comment: Thou shalt not use whitespace in `\bibliography`! Running `bibtex Bug` tells us that, but it is really unfortunately that `latexmk` 1. does not tell us and 2. does not run `bibtex` to tell us ...

Comment: Spaces in comma-separated lists can have [unexpected results in general](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/docsvlist.shtml#spacesinlists). This isn't specific to `\bibliography`.

Comment: I don’t think BibTeX has ever supported spaces after those commas

Comment: Latexmk is actually complaining about not finding ' IEEEabrvb.bib' (with an initial space in the name), not about not finding 'IEEEabrvb.bib'.  I've put quotes in the error message for the next release.  Even so, latexmk's diagnostics do need improving.

Comment: @JohnCollins thanks! By the way, I had suspected something like this at one point earlier on, but note how `IEEEabrv.bib` perfectly aligns with `Non-existent`... 